# Source bash from url only if file from the url exists and hide output

Tags: bash, curl

I've been searching the web but couldn't find the answer for my situation. I believe it's a first?

Anyway, here's what I'm trying to do;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if source <(curl -s -f http://example.com/$1.txt); then
        echo "Found the file"
else
        echo "Couldn't find it"
fi
```

This is supposed to source the bash from `http://example.com/$1.txt` when I run the script like this; `./myscript.sh fileName` while hiding any success of error outputs because I don't want them to show up.

However, while it works fine for the files that exist, it still says `"Found the file"` even if the file isn't there and sources the bash from an empty file because of the `-f` flag. If I remove the `-f` flag then it works and says `"Couldn't find it"` but it also returns an HTTP error since the file isn't there and as I said, I want to hide the errors too.

How can I work this around?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, then `source` happily and successfully execute the empty file as a no-op. You want to check if you retrieved anything *before* you call `source`. For that matter, you probably don't want to blindly execute code received from an outside resource without verifying that you have received what you *expect* to receive. A man-in-the-middle attack could send arbitrary code in place of the file you are attempting to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result code from `source` is simply the last command in the sourced file. If the file is empty (as it will be if `curl` fails) that's a success.

What you can do is guard against an error from `curl` separately.

```sh
if source <(curl -s -f "http://example.com/$1.txt" || echo "exit $?"); then
```